# Restriction to check pairs of elements in XML node

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.0

I have XML file as below

```
        <MyAttributes>
            <MyAttribute User = "CLASS_FROM_1" System = "CLASS1FROM"/>
            <MyAttribute User = "CODE_FROM_1" System = "CODE1FROM"/>
            <MyAttribute User = "CLASS_FROM_2" System = "CLASS2FROM"/>
            <MyAttribute User = "CODE_FROM_2" System = "CODE2FROM"/>
        </Attributes>
```

The point is I want to check if there are pairs of `MyAttribute` elements (CLASS and CODE in each pair), for example

```
        <MyAttribute User = "CLASS_FROM_1" System = "CLASS1FROM"/>
        <MyAttribute User = "CODE_FROM_1" System = "CODE1FROM"/>
```

In case like this:

```
    <MyAttributes>
        <MyAttribute User = "CLASS_FROM_1" System = "CLASS1FROM"/>
        <MyAttribute User = "CLASS_FROM_2" System = "CLASS2FROM"/>
        <MyAttribute User = "CODE_FROM_2" System = "CODE2FROM"/>
    </Attributes>
```

XML is incorrect

Is it possible to define such constraint in XML Schema 1.0 (in XSD file for validation)? Maybe changing hierarchy of XML would solve the problem, but I can't change xml structure.

Comment: What would like to check exactly? That the `System` attribute with value *`CLASSnFROM`* has a corresponding value *`CODEnFROM`* (where *n* is a number) on a different `<MyAttribute>` tag.

Comment: Exactly, as you mentioned I need to check if <MyAttribute> tag with System value CLASSnFROOM has a corresponding value CODEnFROM on a different <MyAttribute> tag. In other words, verify if tags occur only in pairs (CLASSnFROOM, CODEnFROM ), not alone.

Comment: No, not in XML Schema 1.0.   You could do it using assertions in XSD 1.1, but, really, your XML design is fundamentally flawed and should be fixed; elements named "attribute" are a big red flag.